# Maintaining width between absolute elements

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm using a jQuery animation for my menu, and as a consequence need to use position: absolute. I want to keep the same distance between each of my text strings but each is a different width. Using the jQuery width function gives me poor results, is there a better way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menuitem").css('margin-left', -80);
    var url = window.location;
    $('.menulink').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).removeClass('menulink');
    //$(".menuitem").animate({marginLeft: "20px"}, 2000);
    var number = (".menuitem").length;
    var px = number * 40 + 60;
    $($(".menuitem").get().reverse()).each(function (i, e) {
        $(this).delay(i * 200).animate({
            left: px
        }, 1000, 'linear');
        px = px - 80;
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w3mWU/)

Comment: I don't think you need `position: absolute` to animate elements. `position: relative` should work fine.

Comment: On jsFiddle I was having issues with relative and the left attribute, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need absolute position. (or i misunterstand the final purpose)

margin+ display will do it :

```css
.menuitem {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 1em 0 0
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/3bM9L/1

Comment: It doesn't seem to work well with the animation, which was my goal.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to maintain equal distance between each element, as a margin would?

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but some sort of equal spacing would be nice.

Comment: what do you mean ? margin don't do it ?you want them each same width?

Comment: Well, because I'm setting the left position, I don't think the margin really works, look at the animation, the longer strings have smaller space in between them.